# Angular2 md-Dialog with selected option

Tags: angular, templates, dialog, selecteditem

I have a project with a list of items. The idea is, when I select one item and click on it, it should be opened in the modal Dialog window with this item details.

I implemented the onSelected function. This function selects the item and showing it under the list, but not inside the dialog. 
Instead, when my dialog is open it shows the empty dialogue window with a single closing button and without anything.

I'm not really familiar to the Angular and ask you to help me.
I've lost a ton of time and don't understand how to make it work together.

Please see the code snippet below:

I have BikinisComponen

```
<app-bikini-list (bikiniSelected)="selectedBikini= $event"></app-bikini-list>
  <app-bikini-detail [selectedBikini]='selectedBikini'></app-bikini-detail>  
    export class BikinisComponent implements OnInit {
selectedBikini:Bikini;
   constructor( ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }    
}
```

Next BikiniListComponent

```
<div class ="flex-header">
  <h1 class= 'page-title'> Bikini</h1>
 </div>

<div>
<ul class="flex-container">

<app-bikini-item *ngFor="let bikini of bikinis" [bikini]='bikini'
 class="flex-item" (click)="onSelected(bikini)"> </app-bikini-item>

</ul>
</div>
export class BikiniListComponent implements OnInit {
  bikinis: Bikini[] = [];

  @Output() bikiniSelected = new EventEmitter<Bikini>();

  constructor(private suitsService: SuitsService, public dialog: MdDialog, ) { }
  public result;

  public openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BikiniDetailComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bikinis = this.suitsService.getBikinis();
  }

  onSelected(bikini: Bikini) {
    this.bikiniSelected.emit(bikini);
  }

}
```

Next Bikini Item

```
<md-card class="example-card">

  <img md-card-image src={{bikini.imagePath}}>
  <md-card-content>
    <h3>{{bikini.id}}   {{bikini.name}}</h3>
    <h4>Color: {{bikini.color}}</h4>
      <p  class='text-content'>{{bikini.description}}</p> 
  </md-card-content>

</md-card>
export class BikiniItemComponent {

@Input() bikini:Bikini;
bikiniId:number;
selectedBikini:Bikini;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}
public result;

 public openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BikiniDetailComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }


}
```

And Bikini Detail

```
 <div md class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 md-dialog-title> {{selectedBikini?.name}}</h1>
    <h4>{{selectedBikini?.color}}</h4>
    <div md-dialog-content>
      <img src="{{selectedBikini?.imagePath}}" alt="" class="img-responsive">

      <p>{{selectedBikini?.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div md-dialog-actions>
      <a md-fab (click)="dialogRef.close()"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

export class BikiniDetailComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() public selectedBikini:Bikini;

  constructor( public dialog: MdDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

public result;

 public openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BikiniDetailComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

All Information called from my service (which work correctly)

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No, I haven't any errors..but I can use only     or onSelected or openDialog function                                     
    <app-bikini-item *ngFor="let bikini of bikinis" [bikini]='bikini'
 class="flex-item" (click)="onSelected(bikini)"> </app-bikini-item>

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to pass the selected item to the dialog(BikiniDetailComponent) and show it on the dialog, so for this you can use a service as follow.

step 1 -  create a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

import { Bikini } from 'path/to/bikini/model';


@Injectable()
export class SelectedBikiniEventService {
  private defaultBikini:Bikini = <Bikini> {} ;

  private editSelectedBikini:BehaviorSubject<Bikini> = new BehaviorSubject(this.defaultBikini);

  public editItem = this.editSelectedBikini
    .asObservable()
    .distinctUntilChanged();

  changeItem(bikini: Bikini) {
    this.editSelectedBikini.next(bikini);
  }

}
```

step - 2 Instead of emitting an event when the bikini item clicked, use this service method and save the selected bikini item.

inside the BikiniListComponent

```
constructor(private eventService: SelectedBikiniEventService) {}
```

call this method when the item is clicked

```
showSelectedItem(selecteBikini) {
   this.eventService.changeItem(selecteBikini);   
   // open the dialog here
}
```

step - 3 on the dialog Component (BikiniDetailComponent) inject the service as above and subscribe the change on the service's data

```
constructor(private eventService: SelectedBikiniEventService) {
    this.eventService.editItem
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.bikini = data;
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but unfortunately .distinctUntilChanged(); does not exist on type 'Observable<Bikini>'

Comment: Actually, I have already service suitsService: SuitsService, which looks like this `
@Injectable()
export class SuitsService {
  private bikinis: Bikini[] = [
    new Bikini(1, 'Red Lady', "red",
      'Some informationt', 'https://img1.etsystatic.com/137/1/11168310/il_570xN.853638313_3q7r.jpg', []),
    new Bikini(2, 'Salsa dance', "blue", 'Some Informatoion', 'https://fitnesshealthandeverythingelse.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/teal.jpg', []),.....
  ];
  constructor() {}
  getBikinis() {
    return this.bikinis;
  }
}`

Comment: can i see your source code when you use the service please ?